# Delphi use memory stream to read lines

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have made a C++ program that uses ofstream to create 2 files in my disk: one is called `details.obf` and the other is `records.txt`. The file details has only 1 line inside (1 integer) and the file records.txt has a non fixed number of lines (they are all strings).

---

With the code below I can get the value inside the file details. It's pretty simple and I am using a MemoryStream.

```
m := TMemoryStream.Create;
try

 try
  m.LoadFromFile(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'details.obf'));
  m.Read(i, sizeOf(i));
  //other stuff...
 except
  //...
 end;

finally
 m.Free;
end;
```

With the code below instead I am reading the content of the records file:

```
a := TStreamReader.Create('C:\Users\betom\Desktop\records.txt');
 try

  while not(a.EndOfStream) do
   begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(a.ReadLine);
   end;

 finally
  a.Free;
 end;
```

In the second block of code I have used a different class (TStreamReader) and I have written that code looking at embarcadero's documentation. I had to use the `while not(a.EndOfStream) do` because the lenght of records.txt is unknown.

I have seen that MemoryStream (and other classes) are all subclasses of `TStream`. Why I cannot call something like `while not(m.EndOfStream) do` with m a TMemoryStream?

I cannot understand the difference between a MemoryStream and a StreamReader. From what I have understood the latter can read automatically all the values in a given range while the first cannot.

---

Note: I have read on the docs that I can have a TStreamReader and a TStreamWriter and both are fine when I need to create a file that contains some data. I just cannot understand what are memorystream used for if I have the same behavior with a StreamReader.

Comment: TMemoryStream to store data in a dynamic memory buffer that is enhanced with file-like access capabilities

Comment: How about `Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TStreamReader** is a general purpose class for reading text/character data from *any* stream.  It does not support any other form of data in a stream and is not intended for use with any other form of data.

A stream itself might be a file on disk or data on the network or data in memory.  Different stream classes exist to provide stream-access to data from those different sources.

**TMemoryStream** exists specifically to provide access to data in memory as a sequence of bytes, which may be binary data or text/character data or a mixture of both.

Comment: aah ok, so the TStreamReader is always good when I have to read files (with any type of extention)?

Comment: No, not quite.  **TStreamReader** is for reading text/character data from *any* stream.  In the constructor you can pass a reference to a stream (e.g. an instance of a **TMemoryStream**).  For convenience, constructors are also provided to allow you specify a *filename* - this results in the **TStreamReader** internally creating a **TFileStream** to read from that file, but this breaks the "separation of concerns" that stream readers (in general, not this class) normally represent.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question:

> *I have seen that MemoryStream (and other classes) are all subclasses
>   of TStream. Why I cannot call something like `while not(m.EndOfStream) do`
>   with m a TMemoryStream?*

First a correction. It is correct that `TMemoryStream` and **some** other stream manipulating classes (e.g. `TFileStream`) inherit from `TStream`. That is however not the case with `TStreamReader` (and `TStringReader`). These inherit from `TTextReader`, which together with `TTextWriter` and its descendents TStreamWriter and TStringWriter mainly exist to provide familiar classes for `.Net` users.

Here's the hierarchy of some of the discussed classes:

```
TObject
    TStream
        TCustomMemoryStream
            TMemoryStream
                TBytesStream
                    TStringStream
        THandleStream
            TFileStream
        TWinSocketStream
        TOleStream
    TTextReader
        TStreamReader
        TStringReader
    TBinaryReader
```

The answer is that the property `EndOfStream` is declared in `TStreamReader`, iow in a different branch than `TMemoryStream`.

In `TStream` descendents you can use e.g. the `Position` and `Size` properties to determine if you are at the end of the stream.